# Should I define SharedPreferences in the MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I have four `Activities`: `MainActivity`, `HomeActivity`, `SecondActivity`, `ThirdActivity`.

I'm using the `MainActivity` as a welcome screen and my app beginns at HomeActivity. I defined my `SharedPreferences` in `HomeActivity`:

**Outside `OnCreate` method**:

```
SharedPreferences settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

**And inside `OnCreate`:**

```
settings = getSharedPreferences("app_settings", Context.MODE_APPEND);
editor = settings.edit();
```

My Problem is that my `SharedPreferences` only works in `HomeActivity`.
I want to call my `sharedPreferences` in `SecondActivity` as well.

What should I do?

Comment: try [this](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/android-sharedpreferences-singleton-to-make-life-easier-f1d802b6cd8e)

Comment: it just returns the object of `SharedPreferences` corresponding to the given name.. you can access it in any Activity. So you just need to put the same statements on ANother Activity's OnCreate.

Comment: Just use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)`, you can call it in any activity to access the same shared preferences.

Comment: Declare a singleton class foe SharedPreferences and use it anywhere in your project

Answer (score 3):

You can implement a singleton with SharedPreferences like this

```
public class SPManager {

    private static final String TAG = SPManager.class.getName();

    private static SPManager instance;

    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;


    private static final String PREF_NAME = "com.package.app";

    private static final String KEY_NAME = "user_name";


    public static SPManager getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new SPManager(context);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private SPManager(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mPrefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


//    Example
    public void addName(String name) {
        mPrefs.edit().putString(KEY_NAME, name).apply();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mPrefs.getString(KEY_NAME, "John Doe");
    }
}
```

Also you can use this singleton like that : `SPManager.getInstance(context).getName();`

It's simple to use and update it.

Hope to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Please create one class like Datastorage

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

public class Datastorage
{
public static final int INTEGER_KEY = 1;
public static final int STRING_KEY = 2;
public static final int FLOAT_KEY = 3;

public static void WritePreference(String key, String value , Context ctx)
{
    SharedPreferences sp= ctx.getSharedPreferences("GLOBAL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor writer = sp.edit();
    writer.putString(key, value);
    writer.commit();
}
public static void WritePreference(String key, int value , Context ctx)
{
    SharedPreferences sp= ctx.getSharedPreferences("GLOBAL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor writer = sp.edit();
    writer.putInt(key, value);
    writer.commit();
}
public static void WritePreference(String key, float value , Context ctx)
{
    SharedPreferences sp= ctx.getSharedPreferences("GLOBAL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor writer = sp.edit();
    writer.putFloat(key, value);
    writer.commit();
}

public static Object ReadFromPreference(String key , int type , Context ctx)
{
    SharedPreferences sp= ctx.getSharedPreferences("GLOBAL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    Object temp = null;
    if(sp.contains(key)== true)
    {
        if (type == Datastorage.STRING_KEY)
            temp= sp.getString(key,"");
        else if (type == Datastorage.INTEGER_KEY)
            temp = sp.getInt(key,0);
        else if (type == Datastorage.FLOAT_KEY) {
            temp = sp.getFloat(key, 1.0f);
        }

    }
    else
        return temp;
    return  temp;
  }

}
```

After you used this class every where inside your application like,

In My login.java class i store id in sharedpreferences like

```
Datastorage.WritePreference("id",idvalue, getApplicationContext());
```

And after home.java i read this id value like this,

```
String id  = (String) Datastorage.ReadFromPreference("id",Datastorage.STRING_KEY,getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: This code doesn't follow Java conventions about camel case when naming methods. Also you should avoid static methods like these as it difficults testing. If you need to implement a `Singleton` do it well, don't do this

Answer (score 1):

create 1 extend class called BaseActivity

```
class BaseActivity{
     SharedPreferences settings;
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

     onCreate(){
         settings = getSharedPreferences("app_settings", Context.MODE_APPEND);
         editor = settings.edit();
     }
}
```

Then, in any activity just extend it.. ex: SecondActivity extend BaseActivity

```
class SecondActivity extends BaseActivity{
     onCreate(){
        editor.putString("","").apply();
     }
}

class FirstActivity extends BaseActivity{
     onCreate(){
        editor.putString("","").apply();
     }
}

.....
```

Answer (score 1):

simply call this custom method wherever you want the sharedpreference value

```
public void retrivePreference() {

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("app_settings", Context.MODE_APPEND);
    String value1 = setting.getString("key1", null);
    String value2 = setting.getString("key2", null);

}
```