# not able to retrieve values from shared preference

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

In registration activity
I have taken sharedpreferences for saving the mail id and password

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static String registration = "registration";
String name ;
String mail ;
String password ;
String re_password;
String NAME = "name";
String MAIL = "mail";
String PASSWORD = "pass";

sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(registration,MODE_PRIVATE);

final EditText E_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_Rname);
final EditText E_mail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_Rmail);
final EditText E_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.e_Rpassword);

name = E_name.getText().toString().trim();
mail = E_mail.getText().toString().trim();
password = E_password.getText().toString().trim();
SharedPreferences.Editor preference_edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
preference_edit.putString(NAME, name);
preference_edit.putString(MAIL, mail);
preference_edit.putString(PASSWORD, password);
preference_edit.commit();
```

In login aactivity

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
String shared_mail;
String shared_password;
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(registration,MODE_PRIVATE);
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailtxt);
pwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pwdtxt);

stremail = email.getText().toString();
strpwd = pwd.getText().toString();
shared_mail = sharedPreferences.getString("mail", null);
shared_password = sharedPreferences.getString("password", null);

Toast.makeText(login_activity.this, shared_mail + shared_password,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In toast message its showing **null**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @MikeM. can u help please?

Comment: In your login activity did you correctly receive the value of "registration" ?

Comment: check whether your shared key is match..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44691549/should-i-define-sharedpreferences-in-the-mainactivity/44691746#44691746 used this

Comment: use getSharedPreferences() using context like context.getSharedPreferences(registration,MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Done that also. It not retrieving yet

Answer (score 0):

For shared preference you can use [this](https://github.com/tushar-acharya/PrefCompat) light weight library.

add dependency

```
compile 'com.tramsun.libs:prefcompat:0.9.4'
```

Then you need to initialize by adding in your application class or else in any of the initial activity.

```
public class ApplicationClass extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Pref.init(this);
    }
}
```

All done, then for saving values you can

```
Pref.putString("Key", "Value");
```

and for getting

```
Pref.getString("Key", "defaultValue");
```

Hope this helps

> PS: This will help you reduce a lot of code lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just log this value....

```
 mail = E_mail.getText().toString().trim();
```

null value is getting set I guess!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from sanoops solution you can also use the TinyDB library. It is based on shared preferences but simpler to use and you can store variety of types including arraylists and objects. Just sync this in your gradle :

```
compile 'com.mukesh:tinydb:1.0.1'
```

After you have successfully synced your gradle, just initialize the tinyDB in the onCreate method of any activity you want to access your cached data.
Initialize it this way

```
TinyDB tinyDB = new TinyDB(getApplicationContext());
```

To store your data just insert this way;

```
tinyDB.putString("key","myString");
tinyDB.putInt("key",5);
```

In order to call the value in any other activity, just initialize the tinyDB in that activity and retrieve your data this way:

```
tinyDB.getString("key");
tinyDB.getInt("key");
```

You can also store and call arrayLists and Objects.